# Open window event in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to catch open in a new window events from my Firefox extension, but I couldn't find any event that can do this properly in my case. I need this because I want to force an attachment content to download and to open in my PDF viewer extension. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
var windowListener = {
    onOpenWindow: function (aXULWindow) {
        // Wait for the window to finish loading
        var aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
        aDOMWindow.addEventListener("load", function () {
            aDOMWindow.removeEventListener("load", arguments.callee, false); //this removes this load function from the window
            //play with your window here
        }, false);
    },
    onCloseWindow: function (aXULWindow) {},
    onWindowTitleChange: function (aXULWindow, aTitle) {}
};

//to register
Services.wm.addListener(windowListener);
//Services.wm.removeListener(windowListener); //do this to remove
```